# button onClick to activate JQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am still new to JQuery but what I am trying to do is this:

1. Click my edit button and call someFunction()
2. Jquery then will hide my edit button, show my save button, and hide the delete button.
3. Get the item.ID and save as a var for later.

Here is my attemp thus far.

The button set:

```
<td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
         <span style="visibility:hidden">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

         <span class="item-edit-button">
         <button type="button" onclick="someFunction()" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
         </span>

         <span class="item-save-button">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
         </span>

         <span class="item-delete-button">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-lg-4" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Movie", new { id = item.ID })' ;return false;"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
         </span>
</td>
```

my JQuery attempt (without getting the var since I haven't gotten to that point yet)

```
<script>
    function someFunction() {
          someFunction //trying to get current item/value/button/ect..
                .hide()
                .next("span.item-save-button")
                .show()
                .next("span.item-delete-button")
                .hide()
    };
</script>
```

EDIT: How to do this using the answer below

```
function someFunction(element) {
        $(element).hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass element reference like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="someFunction(this)">Click ME</button>
```

and  in function:

```
function someFunction(element) {

                $(element).hide();
                $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
                $(element).show();
                $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();
                $(element).hide();
    }
```

Comment: ah nice! However I must have named things wrong. It hides the Edit button, but does not show the Save and does not hide the Delete

Comment: Hmmm doing the same thing still

Comment: i mistakenly removed ``hide()`` while editing..:P so thats why it not worked

Comment: Well now it hides Edit, Shows Saves, but Delete is still visible hahaha

Comment: why don't you just add some more classes to save and delete like "editMode" and then just do $(element).('.editMode').show()

Comment: yes @miro is right you can add classes as well to make it more simple

Comment: That way you can add more buttons later and the jQuery will be the same

Comment: shouldn't having a class for each span be sufficient though? they are each nested in a span with a class for that reason

Comment: Having more than one class per span is not a big deal

Comment: if your span has class item-delete-button then it should hide delete as well as it is doing for edit

Comment: Yea I mis-copied a name, then removed the extra .hide and .show to get: `$(element).hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();`